# How do I count the number of appearances of any string that is NOT "string1", "string2", "string3" etc.?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is for SQL-Server 2008. Here's an example column:

```
-----------------
|    strings    |
-----------------
|    string1    |
-----------------
|    string2    |
-----------------
|    string3    |
-----------------
|    string4    |
-----------------
|      ...      |
-----------------
```

What would be a query to count the number of appearances of ANY string that is NOT "string1", "string2" or "string3"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT strings, COUNT(*) As Appearances 
FROM tbl
WHERE strings NOT IN('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
GROUP BY strings
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear what you want by the

> count the number of appearances of ANY string that is NOT "string1", "string2" or "string3"?

If you want the number of strings that are not 'string1', 'string2', 'string3' then you want just

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1
WHERE strings NOT IN('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
```

[See it working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/add78/1)

If you want the number of instances of *each string* that aren't 'string1', 'string2', 'string3'  then you need to add a `group by strings` like [Magnus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199944/119477)

Comment: This could be the correct answer, the question is a little vague in regards to "count the number of appearances of ANY string"

Comment: @Magnus I'm guessing you wrote the comment before my last edit. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I meant the number of instances but in my case the number in question is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a result with two columns, the first column will have the string and the second will have the count for that string.  Use the where clause to filter out the string you do not want.

```
SELECT strings, COUNT(strings)
FROM table_name
WHERE strings <> 'string1'
GROUP BY strings
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the relational difference operator, `EXCEPT` e.g.

```
WITH strings
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ( 'string1' ), 
                     ( 'string2' ), 
                     ( 'string3' ), 
                     ( 'string4' )
             ) AS T ( string )
     )
SELECT text_value 
  FROM YourTable
EXCEPT
SELECT string
  FROM strings;
```

Comment: Why make it this complicated when you can do a simple `not in` ?

Comment: @Magnus: one reason: one can replace the CTE with a staging base table or table-valued parameter rather than relying on dynamic SQL.